# Getting customer information in Django RazorPay payment gateway

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, django-views, django-templates, razorpay

I just integrated **Razorpay** payment gateway in my django project and i am new to this payment gateway. When i am initiate the payment razorpay show me an ***payment interface(like this image)*** and there is options for writing  ***customer*** **contact and email**. Here is my question how can i get this two fields back **contact and email** when **customer** click on proceed button.
[image]

Here is my code:
**Template file**

```
            <h2>Product Checkout</h2>
            <p>Product: {{ order_obj.product.name }}</p>
            <p>Total: {{ order_obj.total }}</p>

 <form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
    data-key="rxxxxxxxxxxxxitP7h"
    data-amount= {{order_amount }}
    data-currency={{order_currency}}
    data-buttontext="Pay with Razorpay"
    data-name="xxxxxInc"
    data-description="We are listning"
    data-image="https://www.bihhs.in/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/jj-logo.png"
    data-prefill.name="company name"
    data-prefill.email="abc@gmail.com"
    data-theme.color="#F37254">
</script><input type="hidden" custom="Hidden Element" name="hidden">
</form>
```

**Views.py file**

```
client = razorpay.Client(auth=("rzxxxxxxxaitP7h", "dZH5xxxxxxxxFmzG"))
payment = client.order.create(dict(amount=order_amount, currency=order_currency))
if payment:
   order_obj.mark_paid()  
   print(payment)
   print(payment.get('email'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting an `id` in the response json. As per the docs here [RazorpayAPI Reference](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/server-integration/python/usage/#orders) and you can then get the details of the order with that ID. Then you create a payment with that order ID and then once payment is made you get a payment ID. There are methods to Fetch Payments with a `Payment ID` which should have these details if the user has filled it.

For your Reference, these are python method guidelines for Razorpay:
[Payment Reference Python Razorpay](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/server-integration/python/usage/#payments)

Here's a pseudo-code for the changes:

```
client = razorpay.Client(auth=("rzxxxxxxxaitP7h", "dZH5xxxxxxxxFmzG"))
order_details = client.order.create(dict(amount=order_amount, currency=order_currency))
if payment:
   order_obj.mark_paid()
   payment_id= client.order.payments(str(order_details["id"]))
   payment_details= client.payment.fetch(str(payment_id)
   payment_email= payment_details["email"]
   print (payment)
   print(payment_details)
```